# c# combobox for news article title

Tags: c#, abstract-class

I'm trying to make my own project in c# as practice. I made a form where the user can create a news article, besides that I also made a form where the user can update & delete a news article by selecting the title.

But for some reason i get this error when trying to acces the combobox: *Error  CS0122'UpdateDeleteNewsArticleForm.cbArticleTitle' is inaccessible due to its protection*
I have a feeling that this has to do with the abstract class, but I have to use this.

The code for the abstract class article (where two article types inherit from):

```
public abstract class Article
    {
        protected int articleId;
        protected string articleTitle;
        protected string articleText;

        //properties
        public int ArticleId
        {
            get { return articleId; }
            private set { articleId = value; }
        }
        public string ArticleTitle
        {
            get { return articleTitle; }
            private set { articleTitle = value; }
        }
        public string ArticleText
        {
            get { return articleText; }
            private set { articleText = value; }
        }

        //Constructor
        public Article(int articleId, string articleTitle, string articleText)
        {
            this.articleId = articleId;
            this.articleTitle = articleTitle;
            this.articleText = articleText;
        }

        //Get id method
        public bool GetArticleId(int articleId)
        {
            if(articleId == this.articleId)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        //Override string method
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "The article id is: " + articleId +
                   " The title is: " + articleTitle +
                   " The content is: " + articleText;
        }
    }
```

The code for the combobox:

```
if(rbNewsNormal.Checked)
                {
                    articleManager.AddArticle(new NewsArticle(articleManager.ArticleId, txtNewsTitle.Text, txtNewsText.Text, false, txtNewsByLine.Text, txtNewsSource.Text));
                    articleManager.IncrementArticleId();
                    UpdateDeleteNewsArticleForm.cbArticleTitle.Items.Add(txtNewsTitle.Text);
                }
```

Does someone know how to fix this without removing the abstract aspect?

Comment: Though the duplicate talks about the specific error you're getting (which has nothing to do with your abstract class), there may likely be other errors/problems as well.  It's uncommon to try to directly manipulate a UI control from another class.  You may want to add a public method do your form for that purpose instead and call that method here rather than manipulate the UI control directly from outside the form.  You'll also want to make sure that you're referencing the same instance as the open/visible form and not some new instance, which is a common problem.

Comment: Yeah i just figured out that it probably is because i want to edit a textbox from another form in another form.